# Pyspark KMeans clustering features column IllegalArgumentException

Tags: python, pyspark

```
pyspark==2.4.0
```

Here is the code giving the exception:

```
LDA = spark.read.parquet('./LDA.parquet/')
LDA.printSchema()

from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator

kmeans = KMeans(featuresCol='topic_vector_fix_dim').setK(15).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(LDA)
```

root 
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topic_vector_fix_dim: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)

**IllegalArgumentException:** 
'requirement failed: Column topic_vector_fix_dim must be of type equal to one of the following types: [struct < type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array < int >,values:array < double > >, **array < double >**, array < float > ] but was actually of type **array < double >** .'

I am confused - it does not like my `array <double>`, but says that it may be the input. 
Each entry of the *topic_vector_fix_dim* is a 1d array of floats

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`containsNull` of the features column should be set to `False`:

```
new_schema = ArrayType(DoubleType(), containsNull=False)
udf_foo = udf(lambda x:x, new_schema)
LDA = LDA.withColumn("topic_vector_fix_dim",udf_foo("topic_vector_fix_dim"))
```

After that everything works.

Answer (score 2):

The `containsNull` answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["x1", "x2", "x3"], outputCol = "features")
df = vectorAssembler.transform(df)
df = df.select(['features', 'Y'])
```

Comment: In the question the input feature is a single column already. The question is not about converting multiple columns to a single one.

Comment: @ArturSokolovsky But It did actually solve the problem. The only thing that makes sense is that the library doesn't explicit it, but it internally only recognize VectorAssembler's arrays when training Estimators.