# PySpark Array<double> is not Array<double>

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am running a very simple Spark (2.4.0 on Databricks) ML script:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import LDA

lda = LDA(k=10, maxIter=100).setFeaturesCol('features')
model = lda.fit(dataset)
```

But received following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Column features must be of type equal to one of the following types: [struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>, array<double>, array<float>] but was actually of type array<double>.'
```

Why my `array<double>` is not an `array<double>`?

Here is the schema:

```
root
 |-- BagOfWords: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- size: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- tokens: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: Can please post the output of `dataset.printSchema()`?

Comment: @cronoik there you go

Comment: This stackoverflow answer solved this problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162989/pyspark-kmeans-clustering-features-column-illegalargumentexception

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to convert it into vector form using vector assembler
`from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler`